# CSS style not applied when loading browser extension on debug mode (reactjs)

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm styling a browser extension app but when I try to load it on the browser in debug mode in either firefox or chrome , none of the css styles are applied. My friend doesn't seem to have this issue on his computer. When I do "inspect element" I can change the styles in debug console.

```
    let navItemClasses = 'navItemClass'
    let activeNavItemClasses = 'activeNavItemClass'    
    <header className="mainHeader">
                  </header>
                  <nav className="navBar">
                    <a
                      className={
                        navItemClasses +
                        (selectedMenu === HOME ? activeNavItemClasses : '')
                      }
                      data-action={HOME}
                      onClick={navigate}
                    >
                      Home
                    </a>
                  </nav>
    </header>

    ## style.css

    .mainHeader {
        background-color: var(--second-background);
        height: 100px;
    }


    .navBar {
        display: flex;

    }

    .navItemClass {
        background-color: var(--second-background);
        flex-grow: 1;
        padding: 1rem 1rem;
        color: var(--headline-color);
        font-size: .8rem;
    }

    .activeNavItemClass {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a code where you can show us what you have tried? Try Codesandbox

Comment: @daydreamer its just basic css in a style.css file referencing classNames , cant even manage to make a single property change..

Comment: @wOxxOm I just updated the post... Since it works fine in debug mode on my friends computer I think it may have something to do with mine? I'm on ubuntu 18.04 minimal installation, tried both firefox and chrome..

Answer (score 0):

Put the CSS code inside the `<style>` element, which you put inside the header element on the HTML file. This way you won't need to link files. :)

Comment: its already linked as stylesheet in the html file containing the 'root' div

Comment: the issue you're having is that it's not linked properly, therefore if you take the CSS out the external file and put in the HTML file as explained above, there should be no problem. It's just the easier way to do it.

Comment: that's not it.. its linked properly and works on my friends computer just fine.. please note this is only when loaded locally on debug mode

Comment: ok, I'm not sure why it's like that and I don't think I can help you any more but I would strongly suggest trying putting the code in the HTML file as directed above. If the code originated from your friend's computer there can be issues because of the location of the files, as the files are designed to run from certain places on your computer, and if you change these places (add extra files, or move locations). The code can cease to work in some ways. I would then suggest creating new files of your own and copy and paste the code into them. I can't be sure if this will work though.

Comment: thanks Miriam... its a react app.. i dont see reason why it would work on another computer and not mine.. remember this is only when loaded on debug mode... 
I will do double check on the file paths .. thanks again